# Alarm manager triggered immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hi I am currently working with AlarmManager. I have written a code given below. As per code the AlarmManager should be triggered after 10 Sec, but here in my code the alarm manager triggers immediately. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
        long timeOrLengthofWait = 10000;
        Intent intentToFire = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentToFire, 0);
        alarmManager.set(alarmType, timeOrLengthofWait, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

And My AlarmReciever Class

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumberReciever="5556";
        String message="Alarm Triggered";
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumberReciever, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context," A message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("Alarm ", "Alarm Has been triggered and sms send");
    }
}
```

I have Already added required permissions in manifest.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using an alarm type of `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. That means that the second parameter to `set()` must be the number of milliseconds from now, where now is expressed as `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

If your goal is to have this occur 10000 milliseconds from the time you make the `set()` call, that `set()` call should be:

```
alarmManager.set(alarmType, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+timeOrLengthofWait, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: As an adition, the documentarion says:  "If the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately." The timestamp of 10000 you provided in the question for sure represents a date in the past. This is the reason your alarm was  triggering immediately.
More info in https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set

Comment: The comment above by @androidevil should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you are creating PendingIntent of an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately. Example - Schedule alarm for today 8AM but executing code around 11AM will fire immediately.

Solution:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

long delay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), delay,pendingIntent);`
```

This will fire the event on next day at specified time (i.e 8AM);

Comment: "If you are creating PendingIntent of an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately". Helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks. checked the documentation -  A trigger time. If the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately.(ref https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms under Set a repeating alarm heading)