# AlarmManager Triggers alarm immediately after alarm is set

Tags: push-notification, alarmmanager

### Background

I am using `AlarmManager` to Display Notification every day at 11 am.

### Code

```
mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AlarmReciever.class);
// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, AlarmReciever.REQUEST_CODE,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 11:00 a.m.
Calendar alarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
Log.d("TIME IN MILLI", String.valueOf(alarmCal.getTimeInMillis()));
mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCal.getTimeInMillis(),
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
setBootRecieverEnabled();
```

### Issue:

The Alarm gets fired after a short while when I set the alarm in App.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574632/4669744).

We need to increment alarm date if the time we are setting is passed.

```
mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AlarmReciever.class);
// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, AlarmReciever.REQUEST_CODE,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 11:00 a.m.
Calendar alarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
```

### Solution - Increment date in alarm calendar

```
if(now.after(alarmCal)){
    alarmCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

### ...

```
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
Log.d("TIME IN MILLI", String.valueOf(alarmCal.getTimeInMillis()));
mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCal.getTimeInMillis(),
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
setBootRecieverEnabled();
```

Google should have mentioned this in the docs.